# Updating a globalvar dictionary derived from a globalvar list in a function, after new items adding to global var list while program is executed

Tags: python, function, global-variables, runtime

I have a global list and a global mappings dictionary

```
some_list_of_objects = []
mapping = {i.attr1: i.attr2 for i in some_list_of_objects}
```

While my program runs, new objects are added to some_list_of_objects. I need my mapping dictionary to be updated after new objects are added to the list since in the later part of my program I need to access this updated mapping dictionary.

I know this would be easy if I were to simply duplicate and run the mapping script. However, what I want is a function that updates the global mapping dictionary when called.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: so far I have tried this,

def update_mapping():
     global mapping

#doesn't work.

I've also tried:

def update_mapping():
     mapping = {i.attr1 : i.attr2 for i in some_list_of_objects}

#This doesn't work either, i guess because python is treating this mapping variable as a local variable instead of global variable

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

```
def update_mapping():
   global mapping
   mapping = {i.attr1: i.attr2 for i in some_list_of_objects}
```

Now, whenever update_mapping() is invoked, the mapping dict is updated.